# Tremolo notation for Sixteenth note triplets

Tags: theory, notation

I'm wondering if there's a tremolo notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremolo) for a repeated Sixteenth note triplets like this one for example:

[image: Sixteenth note triplets]

I've only seen the notation for regular rhythm figures like Sixteenth or eight notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would have been notated differently in the 19th century, but contemporary practice is this:
[image]
If it's necessary to make the rhythmic subdivisions clear:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. This would then look like this:

[image]

But then, this would canonically be read as

[image]

so you might want to do

[image]

or maybe use sextuplets instead of triplets.

Comment: Those quarter note shouldn't be dotted, and there should be a '6' under them, not '3'.

Comment: @PiedPiper Note the _or maybe use sextuplets instead of triplets_ at the end. Also the note should be dotted, as else it would correspond to 2/3 of a quarter. See for example here for a real example: https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/6/67/IMSLP04047-SchubertStringQuartetNo14.pdf

Comment: That example is notated according to the practice of Schubert's time, although it's clear enough from the context. Modern practice is to write quarter notes (if you have the book: Gould p.220). It's the words "or maybe" that are wrong (the Schubert has a sextuplet example).